# Asymptotics of Bessel function of first kind

Tags: real-analysis, integration, asymptotics, special-functions, bessel-functions

For $c > 0$, define the function $f_c:[-1,1] \to \mathbb R$ by $f_c(t) := I_0(c\sqrt{(t+1)})$, where $I_0$ is the Bessel function of the first kind. Define $\Delta_c$ by
$$
\Delta_c := f_c(1) - f_c(0) - f_c'(0).
$$
Note that $\Delta_c = I_0(2c)-I_0(c\sqrt{2})-(\sqrt{c}/2)I_1(c\sqrt{2})$

> **Question.** For large $c$, what is a good asymptotic approximation  for $\Delta_c$ ?

**Note.** Already, I'd be fine with good **lower** and **upper** bounds.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have no experience dealing with Bessel functions, so I really don't know how to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$
I_\nu  (x) = \frac{{e^x }}{{\sqrt {2\pi x} }}\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right)} \right)
$$
as $x\to \infty$ with any fixed $\nu \in \mathbb{C}$, the asymptotics is controlled by the first term, i.e.,
$$
\Delta_c = \frac{{e^{2c} }}{{2\sqrt {\pi c} }}\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{c}} \right)} \right)
$$
as $c\to +\infty$. For more information on the asymptotics of the modified Bessel functions, see http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.40.i.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out the asymptotics would be dominated by the first term, but didn't know the asymptotics of this first term itself.